# How to prove $ \frac{\ln^k(1+x)}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty(-1)^{n-k} \begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, harmonic-numbers, stirling-numbers

> Prove the following formula involving Stirling numbers of the first kind:
>   $$\frac{\ln^k(1+x)}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty(-1)^{n-k} \begin{bmatrix} n \\  k \end{bmatrix}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
>   where $\begin{bmatrix} n \\  k \end{bmatrix}$ is the Stirling number of the first kind.

I use this formula (can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)) a lot in my solutions, but I have not found any proof of it yet. Any idea on how to prove it or where to find the proof?

I am tagging harmonic numbers as its very related to this formula.

Thank you.

Comment: Here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html, it is mentioned that the formula it's due to Abramowitz and Stegun in the book Handbook of Mathematical Functions: with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables, at the page 824. Maybe that can help.

Comment: thanks Zacky I will try to find it.

Comment: I checked the book, proof s not that clear, at least for me.  hope someone will provide a nice clear proof here.

Comment: [The Wikipedia Page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) (subsection *Generating Functions*) does a good job in providing a proof.

Comment: Thank you  mrtaurho I will check it.

Comment: @AliShather Is there anything I could improve which discourages you at the moment from accepting my answer?

Comment: @mrtaurho actually I like your solution but I dont know what you mean by accepting your solution. How to accept it? There are a lot of stuff on MSE I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @AliShather There is a small box underneath the up-down-vote button, formed like a checkmark which you can click to accept an answer.

Comment: Got it.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said within the comment section it is sufficient to visit the [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) and therefore no need to invoke some kind of Harmonic Numbers here. Within the subsection *Generating Functions* we eventually find the following paragraph:

> A variety of identities may be derived by maniplulating the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function):
>   \begin{align*}
> H(z,u)=(1+z)^u&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom unz^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)u^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}s(n,k)
> \end{align*}
>   Using the equality
>   $$(1+z)^u=e^{u\log(1+z)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\log(1+z))^k\frac{u^k}{k!}$$
>   it follows that
>   $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty(-1)^{n-k}\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}\frac{z^n}{n!}=\frac{(\log(1+z))^k}{k!}$$

The crucial relations used here are

> \begin{align*}
> &1.&&(x)_n~=~\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)x^k\\
> &2.&&s(n,k)~=~(-1)^{n-k}\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}
> \end{align*}

Which are, as far as I can tell (not being that experienced with Stirling Numbers at all), quite fundamental properties of the Stirling Numbers of the First Kind.

Comment: Thank you this is good.

Comment: @AliShather Glad to help, even though all I did was to find the proof and provide it here :)