# Series representations of powers of logarithms, i.e. $\ln^{m}(n)=\sum\cdots$?$\;\;\;n\ge2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

As you can guess from the tittle, just to satisfy my curiosity, I've been looking for series representations of powers of logarithms, something formally expressed as 
$$
\ln^{m}(n)=\sum_{...}^{\infty}\cdots
$$
where $n\ge2 \;\wedge\;n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So thats it. Have you ever found something like this? Could you post it here or point to reffreneces?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

I think that I was not very clear in my question, So I'm asking for a series valid for $n\ge 2\;\wedge\;n \in \mathbb{N} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291701/how-to-prove-frac-lnk1xk-sum-n-k-infty-1n-k-beginbmatrix) we have:

$$\ln ^k(x)=\sum _{n=k}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n (1-x)^n k! S_n^{(k)}}{n!}$$

where: $ S_n^{(k)}$ is Stirling number of the first kind.

Comment: Unfortunately this only converges for $|z|<1$ (see the wikipedia page). So it is not valid for $n>1$ as I asked for.

Comment: @Neves set $x=1/q$ and note that $\ln^k(1/q)=(-1)^k\ln^k(q)$. Since $q>1$ we have $|1/q|<1$ and the convergence of the series.